# Zooming out gradually to fit slide

Tags: beamer, pdftex, presentations, animations, zooming

I want to zoom out gradually content to fit the slide like in this video (time: 1:11 to 1:15) https://www.coursera.org/learn/robotics-flight/lecture/C7PTa/rotations

How can I do it in beamer presentation?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it not TeX related

Answer (score 2):

In theory you could compile a static version of your slide first and then use beamer overlays to gradually zoom in:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\slide}{\the\beamer@slideinframe} 
\makeatother

\newcommand{\repetitions}{20}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \transduration{0}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \pgfmathparse{1.0+\slide*0.5/\repetitions}
        \node[at=(current page.center)]{
            \includegraphics[page=3,scale=\pgfmathresult]{example-image-duck}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \pause[\repetitions]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In praxis, this will look jagged as the pdf viewer does not change pages fast enough to fool the human eye. However it looks nice if you convert it to video instead of showing the pdf.

Here is an example movie I created with this technique:

https://vimeo.com/773296726#t=600s